# how to insert thousands of posts faster?

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to insert thousands of posts in my database using a script. I read a xlsx file (I test this one only, around 19 seconds to read the 4k rows). I'm using wp_insert_post to create and update_post_meta to add/update the metas of each post. The timing of my script to do this is aroung 20 minutes. I'm looking for ways to do this operation faster. I tried use API Rest, but it's the same timing to insert. And now, I use this code:

```
//i use this 3 functions(I found it on answers in stackoverflow)

wp_suspend_cache_addition(true);
wp_defer_term_counting( true );
wp_defer_comment_counting( true );

//read all file in 20 seconds, and insert a post for each row

//wp_insert_post here, with the all code
```

And then turn to false the 3 functions again. Any tip or trick to improve the speed? I thought in turn all of this in a line of SQL and pass only one big string as query to my database, but I guess that is not safe(wp_insert_posts take care of the data to me, is'nt?)

Comment: inserting a thousand posts at once is a hefty task, is this a custom importer plugin you're building?

Comment: sorry for the bad explanation. I'm at work. There are 4600 rows in my XLSX file, each is a post. Yeah, it's a plugin.

Comment: Try one or more of the following: using WP CLI, setting SHORTINIT and only include what you absolutely need, or running the migration locally and then migrating the database.

Comment: Do they have similar titles by any chance?